# iPhone - Another Objective-C Memory leak with SBJsonParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, memory-leaks, asihttprequest

I'm really new to iPhone development and Stack Overflow questions. I've been doing my first app since January.

My app has a memory leak related to SBJsonParser. After some googling I found another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983534/iphone-objective-c-memory-leak-with-sbjsonparser) here on stackoverflow. Thanks to the function that Konrad77 posted on his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983534/iphone-objective-c-memory-leak-with-sbjsonparser/4983610#4983610), I changed some lines of my app. But I'm still getting memory leaks. I would appreciate some help. I'm using AsiHttpRequest 1.8 and JSONframework 3.0beta1.

Instruments tell me that the leak is on the following line of MyLists.m for 99.2%:

```
resultObject = [self.model JSONObjectForRequest:request];
```

The other 0.8% goes to the following line of MyLists.m:

```
[self.model.myLists addObject:userData];
```

Both of previous lines are inside listaGetRequestOnResult function. Here you have all related code:

**-MyLists.h:**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "Model.h"
    #import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"

    @interface MyLists : UITableViewController {
        Model *model;
        NSObject *resultObject;
    }

    @property (assign) Model *model;
    @property (nonatomic,assign) NSObject *resultObject;

    @end
```

**-MyLists.m:**

```
#import "MyLists.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"

@implementation MyLists


@synthesize model;
@synthesize resultObject;

-(void)loadListData {
    [self showWaitPopup:CARGANDO];

    //Remote listaGet operation
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.model.operationsURL];

    ASIFormDataRequest *postRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [postRequest setPostValue:@"listaGet" forKey:@"action"];
    [postRequest setPostValue:@"JSON" forKey:@"format"];

    [postRequest setDelegate:self];
    [postRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(listaGetRequestOnResult:)];
    [postRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(listaGetRequestOnFault:)];
    [postRequest startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)listaGetRequestOnResult:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request {
    [self hideWaitPopup:CARGANDO];

    resultObject = [self.model JSONObjectForRequest:request];

    NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *)resultObject;
    NSNumber *errorCode = [data valueForKey:@"errorCode"];
    if ([errorCode intValue] == 0) {
        //Remote operation did end successfully
        NSMutableArray *userData = [data valueForKey:@"data"];

        //Set list into model For now, only one component for the table
        [self reinitializeTableList:FALSE];
        self.model.myLists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self.model.myLists addObject:userData];
        [self.model.myLists retain];
    } else {
        //Remote operation did end succesfully but returned and error
        [model reportError:[data valueForKey:@"errorText"] withTitle:@"Error"];

        [self reinitializeTableList:FALSE];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)listaGetRequestOnFault:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request {
    [self hideWaitPopup:CARGANDO];

    NSError *error = [request error];
    [model reportError:[error localizedDescription] withTitle:@"Error de conexión"];

    [self reinitializeTableList:TRUE];
}

-(void)reinitializeTableList:(BOOL)reloadTableData {
    if (self.model.myLists) {
        [self.model.myLists release];
    }
    self.model.myLists = nil;
    if (reloadTableData) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.model = [Model getModel];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self loadListData];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    model = nil;
    resultObject = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

**-Model.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"

@interface Model : NSObject {
    NSString *operationsURL;
    NSString *imagesBaseURL;
    NSMutableArray *myLists;
}

@property (retain) NSString *operationsURL;
@property (retain) NSString *imagesBaseURL;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *myLists;

+ (Model*) getModel;
//+ (id) allocWithZone:(NSZone *) zone;
+ (void) initModel;
- (void)reportError:(NSString*)mensaje withTitle:(NSString*)withTitle;
- (NSObject*)JSONObjectForRequest:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request;

@end
```

**-Model.m:**

```
#import "Model.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "JSON.h"

@implementation Model

static Model *uniqueInstance = nil;

@synthesize operationsURL;
@synthesize imagesBaseURL;
@synthesize myLists;

+ (Model*) getModel {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (uniqueInstance == nil) {
            uniqueInstance = [[Model alloc] init];
            [self initModel];
        }
    }
    return uniqueInstance;
}

/*+ (id) allocWithZone:(NSZone *) zone {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (uniqueInstance == nil) {
            uniqueInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
            return uniqueInstance;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}*/

+ (void) initModel {
    //URL
    uniqueInstance.operationsURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SOME_URL"];
    uniqueInstance.imagesBaseURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SOME_URL"];
}

-(void)reportError:(NSString*)mensaje withTitle:(NSString*)withTitle {
    UIAlertView *alertDialog;
    alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:withTitle
                                             message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mensaje]
                                            delegate: nil 
                                   cancelButtonTitle: @"Aceptar"
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertDialog show];
    [alertDialog release];
}

- (NSObject*)JSONObjectForRequest:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request {
    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
    NSObject *object=[jsonParser objectWithString:[request responseString] error:nil];
    if (object == nil) {
        [self reportError:[jsonParser error] withTitle:@"Error librería JSON"];
    }
    [jsonParser release], jsonParser = nil;
    return object;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [operationsURL release];
    [imagesBaseURL release];
    [myLists release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Here you have screenshots of Instruments:

[image: Instruments leaks 1]

[image: Instruments leaks 2]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this perhaps on a separate thread?

Comment: could you try [[SBJsonParser alloc] init] instead of [SBJsonParser new]?

Comment: **@Richard J. Ross III:** I have not programmed threads on my app I don't know if this helps But the first time I call `model = [Model getModel];` is in the function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of my AppDelegate
**@Zaky German:** I have tried `[[SBJsonParser alloc] init]` and I'm still getting the same memory leaks I have also tried to set the jsonParser as a retained property in model Then I added and if: `if (!jsonParser) {
  jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
 }` but i does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your leak (it actually has two extra retains):

```
self.model.myLists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.model.myLists addObject:userData];
[self.model.myLists retain];
```

You probably want something like this:

```
self.model.myLists = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:userData];
```

I also wouldn't use `assign` properties like you have done.

Comment: Thanks a lot **@tc**. This helped me to get rid of memory leaks on my app. After reading links on **@BillDudney** answer, I understood why you tell me to avoid `assign`attribute. So I will use `retain` instead (for both `model` and `resultObject`).

Comment: Of course, then you need to change dealloc to do `self.model = nil` and `self.resultObject = nil`, or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Great job posting code, and big high five for using Instruments. I am constantly amazed how many developers don't use it.

I know you probably have already read this, but please re-read it;

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594

Code like this;

```
self.model.myLists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.model.myLists addObject:userData];
[self.model.myLists retain];
```

shows that you have not grasped the concept of encapsulation.

It is really important that `model` be in charge of that list rather than an external object. Add code in your model class to create that list in the `init` method then add methods that you can call that will add items to that list.

Calling `alloc` means that you have one retain in this scope, then calling `retain` again means you have two. I'm sure there are other similar problems.

To help understand the memory management rules please read this;

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

tc's advice above is golden, don't use `asign` unless you understand why you are using it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1

has tons more detail on what the various options mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot **@BillDudney**. I really appreciate your advices because they helped me to comprehend my mistakes and **@tc.'s** answer.